# Counting patterns from table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in a Mysql table

```
ID   |  code | code order
   1 |  1 | 1
   1 |  2 | 2
   1 |  3 | 3
   2 |  1 | 1
   2 |  2 | 2
   2 |  3 | 3
   3 |  1 | 1
   3 |  4 | 2
   3 |  5 | 3
   4 |  1 | 1
   4 |  4 | 2
   4 |  5 | 3
   4 |  6 | 4
```

How would I write a query to return the following results

```
code pattern 1,2,3 = 2 (count)

code pattern 1,4,5 = 1 (count)

code pattern 1,4,5,6 = 1 (count)
```

basically I need to find out the most popular code sequence, each sequence is grouped by an unique ID. The order the codes of the is also important. i.e

1,4,5,6 is different to 1,5,4,6

cheers

Comment: Does the order of values in the sequence matter?

Comment: yes, also a finished pattern is a collection of codes based on id.

Comment: So, given that rows in MySQL represent unordered sets, how do you know what order the sequence is in?!

Comment: yer just realized that , If I add an code order column would this work?, I have edited the original post to show this

Comment: Yes, an auto-incrementing id would work too

Comment: between both of you got it working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, this is probably most easily done using two aggregation:

```
select pattern, count(*)
from (select id, group_concat(code order by code) as pattern
      from t
      group by id
     ) p
group by pattern;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Comment: the problem i have now is if I add

id | code

4 | 1

4 | 2

4 | 5

to the data

the results show 

code pattern 1,2 = 3

is there a way to treat the pattern as an collection based on ID

Comment: @Fear_The_Mull . . . I don't understand your comment.  The patterns *are* based on `id`.  If you have duplicates, you can use `group_concat(distinct code order by code)`.  Note:  I changed the answer to include `order by`, which is important for this purpose.